# AND Condition Not Working

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I have two objects X and Y .Need to write validation on Y object if Picklist value in Object X is set to active and it should satisfy all other conditions also but I am able to save the record if one value is not blank which shouldn't

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(x__r.Service_Type__c,"active"),
ISBLANK(Type__c),
ISBLANK(Min_Age__c),
ISBLANK(Max_Age__c ))
```

Here  type is multiselect picklist value .Can anyone help in resolving this

Comment: Do you try also add isNull function?

Comment: Even I have added Null but validation rule was not firing,

Comment: isNull is in the opossite. It should be not Null. Could you change the question adding Isnull also in your formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AND` means ALL must be satisfied, so if any one of the fields are NOT blank the rule will evaluate to false.

I assume what you mean is you want to prevent the action if any of the other fields are blank

You want `OR` on the inner items which means Any of them evaluate to true then return true:

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(x__r.Service_Type__c,"active"),
    OR(
      ISBLANK(Type__c),
      ISBLANK(Min_Age__c),
      ISBLANK(Max_Age__c )
    )
)
```

This evaluates to :

```
AND( TRUE, OR([True if any are true]))
```

If both AND conditions are true then validation returns true and prevents action

Comment: I need all conditions to be satisfied.Even if one condition is not satisfied it should throw error

Comment: @anjali - so you want them to all be blank?

Comment: No I dont want any condition to be blank

Comment: @anjali - The above will prevent action if the Picklist is active and Any of the other field ARE blank. Which is what you are saying you want

Comment: +1 for being the first (and most correct) answer. This is really the one that should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INCLUDES`with multiselect picklist:

```
AND(
 INCLUDES(x__r.Service_Type__c,"active"),
 OR(
  ISBLANK(Type__c),
  ISBLANK(Min_Age__c),
  ISBLANK(Max_Age__c )
 )
)
```

Comment: service type is a picklist ,Type is a multiselect picklist

Comment: Go with Eric's formula then

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace it as -

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(x__r.Service_Type__c,"active"),
    OR(
        ISBLANK(Type__c),
        ISBLANK(Min_Age__c),
        ISBLANK(Max_Age__c )
    )
)
```

This will going to check Service_Type is active and any of the value is blank, you will get error.
Otherwise, if Service_Type is active and all values are there, there will going to be no validation error and record will be saved.

Comment: How does this differ from the other answers? Just clutters up the thread to repost. If it does please add to the answer as it is not obvious what makes it different